# How to Regex.Replace just my captured group?

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to insert a date into an SQL query string so that I don't have to keep modifying two different SQL files.

I thought I could just look for the Start Date that I declare in my SQL Query and replace the date that is set there currently. So I have a regex that captures the date that is currently there and want to replace it with a new date.

SQL

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2014-06-06'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2015-07-18'
```

C#

```cs
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2018,06,06);
string PerformanceQuery = File.ReadAllText("<PathtoSql>");     
Regex startDateReplace = new Regex("StartDate DATE = '(.*?)'");
string newPerformanceQuery = startDateReplace.Replace(PerformanceQuery, $"1" + startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")");
```

Expected:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2018-06-06'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2015-07-18'
```

Actual:

```
DECLARE @12018-06-06
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2015-07-18'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the pieces you want to remain unchanged and include them in the replacement.

```
Regex startDateReplace = new Regex("(StartDate DATE = ').*?(')");
string newPerformanceQuery = startDateReplace.Replace(PerformanceQuery,
        "${1}" + startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" + "$2");
```

Note the `${1}` in the replacement string. This is because the new date string starts with a digit and, without the `${1}` the replacement looks like `$12018-` which asks for the (non-existant) capture number 12018.

You could simplify the above in this case by recognising that both the capture groups have fixed content, and rewrite them as below. I generally prefer to use the captures as it makes it clear that the text is not changed, it reduces the opportunity for errors if the search strings change (and only one copy is modified), and it works for cases when the strings are not fixed.

```
Regex startDateReplace = new Regex("StartDate DATE = '.*?'");
string newPerformanceQuery = startDateReplace.Replace(PerformanceQuery,
        "StartDate DATE = '" + startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" + "'");
```

Comment: I see. However when I use this it is failing to capture the first section and is replacing it with: DECLARE @$12018-06-06'

Comment: @M.Waddelow Please show the whole `string ... startDateReplace.Replace(...);` statement that is giving the wrong result.

Comment: `string newPerformanceQuery = startDateReplace.Replace(PerformanceQuery, "$1" + startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "$2");`

Comment: That looks fine. What is the `Regex startDateReplace = ...;` line?

Comment: `Regex startDateReplace = new Regex("(StartDate Date = ').*?(')");`

Comment: You found one of the wrinkles with computers, they do what you ask, not what you want. See the modified answer, the important bit relates to `${1}`.

Comment: Ahh I see that's really interesting. If that's the case why is not standard to just always include the {} braces?

Comment: Convention and history. I believe some Regex systems only allow 9 capture groups. Regexs used while editing (i.e. in text editors) seldom use many captures, so adding the curly braces would add a lot of unnecessary typing.

Answer (score 1):

Just use positive lookbehind: `(?<=StartDate DATE = ')[^']*?`

Comment: How does this method preserve the closing single prime (`'`)?

Comment: @AdrianHHH He probably also needs to use look ahead for that

Comment: @AdrianHHH Corrected that.

Comment: When I use this in an online tool to understand the regex it mentions a warning saying that: The expression can return empty matches and may match indefinitely in some use cases. Is this a concern?

Comment: @M.Waddelow No, I don't think so.